# Can Nodejs use the async and await fucntionality on a single core processor?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, async-await, blocking

I was just going through the way node js works internally. It essentially sends the blocking operations ie the asynchronous tasks to the thread pool and the rest tasks are kept waiting. So what would happen if we run a nodejs application on a single core application?

Again, this is just my though process, I might be wrong. I think that both the blocking and the non blocking operations will be executed on the same core. So, does that mean that the application might be unresponsive while the blocking task is running? And does it mean that we need atleast a dual core CPU to run any nodejs application that wants to perform asynchronous operations?

Comment: Mostly blocking I/O is waiting for I/O. It doesn't need to use the CPU.